# how can use this load page plugin (only for js) when my php codes are working?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

how can use this loading page plugin (only for js) when my php codes are working?
I don't know java script/ajax! but I understand php/css/html :)

this plugin named "PACE" only load progress bar for javascript works (automatically) but I want use it for my php codes when they're running. example my thumb generator takes 30s.

gethub link for pace: https://github.com/HubSpot/pace

Documentation of pace (that I don't know how works!): http://github.hubspot.com/pace/

my time-consuming PHP code in the page:

```
dothumbgen($a,$b);
```

how can use PACE for this function?

Answer (score 0):

To use this plugin, follow steps bellow:

1. Download this PACE jQuery plugin in: http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/
2. Include the plugin in your page:

   ```html
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HubSpot/pace/v0.5.6/pace.min.js"></script>
   ```
3. Put this code in this your footer document:

   ```html
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
       Pace.restart();
   }).ajaxStop( function() { 
       Pace.stop();
   }).ajaxError( function(event, request, settings) { 
       Pace.stop();
   }).ajaxComplete( function(event, request, settings) { 
       Pace.stop();
   });
   </script>
   ```